# Loop through MVC model and return

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model

Here is my code for the model for which returns names and ids...

```
public class AccountType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static AccountType[] ValidAccountTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
        {
            new AccountType
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Vendor"
            },
            new AccountType
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Customer"
            },
            new AccountType
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name = "Demo"
            }
        };
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to return in html and loop over with the following:

```
@model DemoApplication.Models.AccountType

@foreach (var x in Model.Name)
{
    <p> @x </p>          
}
```

I get the error of "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Not quite sure what to do here as I am VERY new to MVC altogether...I have read up on the documentation a bit to not avail.

Update: figured it out myself through trial and error!

```
@foreach (var x in DemoApplication.Models.AccountType.ValidAccountTypes)
    {
        <p> @x.Name </p>
    }
```

Comment: Please also post the Actionmethod in the relevant Controller, as this is where you would pass the ViewModel to the View.

Comment: `Model.Name` is a string, you want to loop over `Model.VaidAccountTypes` and output `@x.Name`.

Comment: Thank you Paul that makes sense, however when I change the Loop to that it still errors

Comment: I have figured it out, thanks all

Comment: Ideally, you would not need to use statics directly in your View. I prefer to keep the usage of static classes to a minimum, especially in a webapps!

Consider adhering to the MVC principle by making a ViewModel class which contains a collection of AccountTypes. Your controller instantiate this model and pass it to the view by using `return View(model);`

Then, in your View you could enumerate the AccountTypes by using `foreach(var at in Model.ValidAccountTypes)`

Answer (score 1):

I hope you got the solution by yourself, but you can also try with the following code, which have advantage

```
@model DemoApplication.Models.AccountType

@foreach (var x in Model.ValidAccountTypes)
{
    <p> @x.Name  </p>          
}
```

By putting the above, you can have strongly type views , that will useful in multiple ways.

**Advantage of strongly typed views:**

We get
1. Intellisense and
2. Compile-time error checking

Hope the above was useful, kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks

Karthik